# Regex to get a value

Tags: java, regex

I want to find a regex to find the value of originaldbname in the below query where tablename will be passed as argument. Is it possible. Tried many things but now working.

```
REPLACE WITH viewdbname.tablename as locking row for access select * from originaldbname.tablename
```

.

edit:
I am running the below program to the value of original.

```
String query = "REPLACE WITH viewdbname.tablename as locking row for access select * from original.tablename";
Pattern p=Pattern.compile("from\\s+(?:\\w+\\.)*(\\w+)($|\\s+[WHERE,JOIN,START\\s+WITH,ORDER\\s+BY,GROUP\\s+BY])",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher m=p.matcher(query);
while(m.find()) System.out.println(m.group(1));
//But it is returning me tablename... I want to get "original" as output.
```

Comment: Please, explain better your question

Comment: I am running the below program to the value of original.
`
String query = "REPLACE WITH viewdbname.tablename as locking row for access select * from original.tablename";
     Pattern p=Pattern.compile("from\\s+(?:\\w+\\.)*(\\w+)($|\\s+[WHERE,JOIN,START\\s+WITH,ORDER\\s+BY,GROUP\\s+BY])",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

     //test
     Matcher m=p.matcher(query);
     while(m.find())
         System.out.println(m.group(1));`

But it is returning me tablename... I want to get "original" as output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you had `(?:\\w+\\.)*(\\w+)` where `(?: )` is a non-matching group and your first matching group is `(\\w+)` after the `.` dot.

You could go with this shorter regexp to capture the optional word before the `.` dot:

`Pattern.compile("from\\s+(?:(\\w+)\\.)?\\w+",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);`

Comment: Thank you. This was what i needed

Answer (score 1):

If you just want "original" this will do:

```
    String query = "REPLACE WITH viewdbname.tablename as locking row for access select * from original.tablename";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("from\\s+(.+)\\.");

    Matcher m = p.matcher(query);
    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
```